# Create dynamically JSON keys in a JS loop

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Javascript code with a JSON variable that works well.

```
var valuesJSON = {
    projects: {
        0: {value: 0, price: 0},
        1: {value: 0, price: 0},
        2: {value: 0, price: 0},
        3: {value: 0, price: 0},
        4: {value: 0, price: 0},
        5: {value: 0, price: 0},
        6: {value: 0, price: 0},
        7: {value: 0, price: 0},
    }
  }
```

I want to make it more scalable, so that it will read the number of entries from a constant. I tried the following but the for loop in the variable is not allowed. Any ideas?

```
const NUM_PROJECTS = 8
var valuesJSON = {
    projects: {
        for (var i=0; i < NUM_PROJECTS; i++) {
            i: {value: 0, price: 0},
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use bracket notation if variable is to be used as key!

Comment: `var valuesJSON = {
    projects: {
    }
  };         for (var i=0; i < NUM_PROJECTS; i++) {
            valuesJSON.projects[i]= {value: 0, price: 0}
        }`

Comment: If all the keys are consecutive and numeric, why isn't `projects` an *array*?

Comment: As in var `valuesJSON = {
    projects: [
{value: 0, price: 0},
{value: 0, price: 0},
{value: 0, price: 0},
{value: 0, price: 0},
{value: 0, price: 0},
{value: 0, price: 0},
{value: 0, price: 0},
{value: 0, price: 0} /* No trailing comma */
]
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add properties to `projects` using `for` loop. [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) needs to used since  `variable` is being used as key.

```
//Create object
var valuesJSON = {
   projects : {}
}

//Iterate and add properties
for (var i = 0; i < NUM_PROJECTS; i++) {
    valuesJSON.projects[i] = {
        value: 0,
        price: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat you by 8 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate with `NUM_PROJECTS` and generate new properties with the wanted result.

```js
const NUM_PROJECTS = 8
var valuesJSON = { projects: {}};

for (var i = 0; i < NUM_PROJECTS; i++) {
    valuesJSON.projects[i] = { value: 0, price: 0 };
}

console.log(valuesJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first make a javascript object.

```
var object = {};
```

You can then edit properties( object.something) via array access.

```
 object.something == object['something']
```

so to set a value in an object, you can do

```
  object['something'] = array_counter
```

Not sure what you wanted, so I added both arrayinfying to an object and putting it in as an object.

```js
var json = {}
var projects = {};
var projectsArr = [];
for(c=0;c<100;c++) {
     var project_entry = {
                              name: 'project'+c,
                              a:c+1,
                              b:c*2
                              };    
         
     projects[project_entry.name] = project_entry;

     projectsArr.push(project_entry);
}
json['projects'] = projects;
json['projects_as_array'] = projectsArr;
console.log(JSON.stringify(json,null,2));
```